# how can I create filesystem on the additional drive

Tags: xen, vps

I have a dedicated server with Xen virtualization and I have many VPSs on it

I requested from datacenter(Hetzner) to add another HDD

but now how can I setup the additional HDD to use it for creating VPS server?

Comment: Which tools do you use to create VPS servers?

Comment: did you use `lvm` when you first set up the Xen server?  If so, just add the new drive (or a partition from it) to the volume group you use for creating VM disks.

Answer (score 0):

Run `lsblk` or `blkid` to find the block device node of the new drive (it will probably be `/dev/xvdb` or similar).

Then you can partition the disk device and format the partition device(s).  e.g. if the new drive is `/dev/xvdb`:

- check to make sure you are not about to overwrite your
  original drive (probably `/dev/xvda`)
- check again because paranoia about potentially dangerous commands never hurts
- `fdisk /dev/xvdb`
- create partition(s)
- format partition(s) with, e.g., `mkfs.ext4 /dev/xvdb1`

Comment: i just re-read your question and am not sure if this is a relevant answer.  this answer is for adding a new drive/block-device in a VM guest.  But re-reading your Q, it sounds like you want to add the new drive to the Xen server?